# How to read multiple servers log files in graylog?

Tags: graylog2, graylog

In our application we want to read logs from 2 different servers i.e apache tomcat and Jboss and want to monitor the logs. I have tried to search online to how to configure it but not albe to understand clearly about how can i implement it in graylog. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send logs from an arbitrary number of applications and systems to Graylog (even on the same input).

Simply configure your applications and systems to send logs to Graylog and create an appropriate input for them.

See http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/sending_data.html for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you were able to send your logs to graylog server. [Centralized logging using graylog](http://devopsideas.com/centralized-logging-using-graylog/) will help newbies to get started with graylog and the article explains use cases like integrating apache, nginx, mysql slow query logs to graylog. This covers various ways like sending logs via syslog, graylog apache module, filebeat etc. which most articles miss out explaining in detail.